# Unwanted BackgroundImage refreshing

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, refresh, transparency

I have a form with a background image set and a label that acts as a timer's output on it. The label is located in a transparent table layout panel. Unfortunately, with every tick of the timer the background visibly refreshes. How can I prevent this?

This is the function that is called with every tick.

```
        private void DisplayCountry()
    {
        if (sel.Count == 1) 
        {
            country_out.Text = "No countries chosen.\nPlease select some.";
            timer_out.Visible = false;
        }
        else{
        timer_out.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", (sel[i].elapsed / 60)) + ":" + String.Format("{0:00}", (sel[i].elapsed % 60));
        if (sel[i] == "sent")
        {
            country_out.Text = "No countries left.";
            timer_out.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            timer_out.Visible = true;
            country_out.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
            country_out.Text = sel[i].name;
            if (sel[i].elapsed > REDTIME)
                timer_out.ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue;
            else
                timer_out.ForeColor = Color.Tomato;
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The following should be nested in an if statement to see if they are already set to the appropriate value (they are getting reset every time it hits them): timer_out.Visible = true;
country_out.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
country_out.Text = sel[i].name;

Answer (score 0):

setting the ForeColor will refresh the image even if it is already that color.  Before setting it check to see if it is already that color.

Comment: I nested everything except the actual timer string update (since that has to update every second) in respective if statements, commented out the font color changing completely, and I still get the same issue. I'd be grateful for any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I got rid of the TableLayoutPanel, sacrificing some alignments, and used a PictureBox as a background. The PictureBox causes no refreshing trouble, I guess it's optimized for that purpose. Thanks for the responses.